# How to change my git default directory to main

Tags: github

I create a branch in my git repository (called 'pmc') and it is becoming the default directory. Now, I would like to move the files over to main, but when I try to change the default directory, only 'pmc' show up. How come main is missing?
[image]

appreciate any kind help.

Answer (score 1):

This post is helpful

https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/git-rename-master-to-main/

To rename branch use

```
git branch -m pmc main
```